# Declaring 2D Arrays with Variable Dimensions

Tags: c++

I know if you have a 2D array `array[i][j]` then `j` must be declared and you cannot get the second one as input by user. Is there any way to get both a 2D array's length and height as variables?

```
cin>>i;
cin>>j;
int array[i][j];
```

I have tried asking the user for two variables and set those as the arrays height and length but it didn't work.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int a;
int b;
cin>>a;
cin>>b;
int array[a][b];
```

Comment: C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), you should use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. C++ also doesn't have "2d" arrays, what you're trying to do is creating an array *of arrays* which can be translated to a vector of vectors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Variable length array is not an option in C++. You may have it in some compilers as an extension supporting variable length array of C.

One solution to your problem is [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(a, (std::vector<int>(b)));
```

Live on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/_YvQGE)